# Ruby on Rails: Adding a local image in a Google Maps marker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a page `show_map.html.erb` that displays a Google Map (currently working great). I want to add an image instead of the pin marker on the map. I have Googled a lot for this question, and found resources such as [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083422/adding-image-to-google-maps-marker-for-this-code). However, my current solution doesn't work.

Do I have to upload an image before using it? Moreover, why can't I use images like `public/alert.png` OR `app/asset/images/alert.png`? I referred to [the Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays) too, but I can't understand the examples.

My controller:

```ruby
def show_map
  @location = Location.find(params[:id])
  @address = @location.landmark.gsub(","+")+",+"+@location.place.gsub(","+")+",+"+@location.country
  p @address
end
```

My view:

```js
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=<my api key>&sensor=true"> type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                      '</div>'+
                      '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" ><font color="#FF0000"><%=@location.title%></font></h2>'+
                      '<div id="bodyContent" >'+
                      '<p><%=@location.description%></p>'+
                      '<p><a href="http:www.google.com">'+
                      'more info</a> (created on <%=(@location.created_at).strftime("%A, %d/%m/%Y")%>)</p>'+
                      '</div>'+
                      '</div>';
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });
  //set the image
  //var image = '/assets/images/alert.png';
  // Enable the visual refresh
  google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

  var geocoder;
  var map;        
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 17,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    //var image = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/alert.png";
    //code to search the address
    //var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var address='<%= @address.parameterize %>';
    //alert(address);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          title:"<%=@location.title%>",
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          visible: true,
          draggable: true,
          icon: image
        });

        //animation for marker
        function toggleBounce() {
          if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
          } else {
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
          }
        }

        //commented as show the info ON click on the marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
        //listener for animation
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map" align="right" style="min-height: 500px; height: 400px; width: 400px"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: are you using the gmaps4rails gem? https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) gem and presuming you've added all dependencies and scripts You will will have something very similar to the following in your controller. You would replace "XYZ" and add your own web address.

```
def index
  @XYZs = XYZ.all

  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@XYZ) do |XYZ, marker|
  marker.lat XYZ.latitude
  marker.lng XYZ.longitude
  marker.infowindow XYZ.artist
  marker.picture({
    url: "WWW.YourWebAddressHere.com",
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
})
end
```

There are live samples and video documentation for the gem that I found quite helpful.